# file:// scheme and content:// scheme confusions || ANDROID

Tags: android, android-intent, android-contentprovider

As android is increasing its security and changing some stuff now a days to make Android OS more secure to Vulnerabilities, its a good thing to understand new structure for developers to get into it.
I have been away from development from last couple of years.I just noticed that some stuff have been changed e.g file scheme of URI.

**Case 1 :** :
I am launching camera intent with custom URI mentioned below.

```
var takePictureIntent = Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE)
    // Ensure that there's a camera activity to handle the intent
    if (takePictureIntent.resolveActivity(packageManager) != null) {
        // Create the File where the photo should go
        var photoFile: File? = null
        try {
            photoFile = createImageFile()
        } catch (ex: IOException) {
            // Error occurred while creating the File
        }
        // Continue only if the File was successfully created
        if (photoFile != null) {
            val photoURI: Uri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(this,
                    BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID + ".fileprovider",
                    photoFile)
            takePictureIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, photoURI)
            startActivityForResult(takePictureIntent, REQUEST_TAKE_PHOTO)
        }
    }
```

photoURI is custom URI.
When i took picture and check URI it has file:// in start from where i can get file path and i can do some stuff with it(i am uploading it to server)

**Case 2**

I am launching simple intent to pick image from gallery

```
        val intent = Intent()
    intent.type = "image/*"
    intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_ALLOW_MULTIPLE, true)
    intent.action = Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT
    startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select Picture"), TYPE_IMAGE)
```

and now when i pick image and check URI its has content:// in start. And the trouble starts when i try to get file path from it. i have been searching into SOF but none of solutions worked for me.

My main purpose it get file path is that i want to pick file from device and upload it to server.But with content:// scheme i can not make a file from URI and thus can not send this file server.

i just read [CommonsWareBlog](https://commonsware.com/blog/2016/03/15/how-consume-content-uri.html) about scheme system. it cleared few things but i still don't know how can i switch from content:// too file:// in my onActivityResult!

i would like to mention it again that current answers on SOF are not working for me that's why i have to ask this question in details.

I am using  7.0 device emulator

> This is just an example of my problem in actual i am picking up PDF and DOCX files and want to upload them on server and after picking files i have URI with content:// scheme and i can not make a file and send to server.

i am not sure what i am missing about schemes.
I hope this question will help many other developers which are new to file system.

**pleasure try to explain by code example according to my problem of picking file from intent (if you like)**

Answer (score 5):

Since Android 7.0, returning `file://` scheme is discouraged ([android changelog](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/nougat/android-7.0-changes.html#perm)), since it can leak files from private folders. You can still encounter it, especially when using apps that target below Nougat.

Short answer is when you query for `Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT` You receive `content://` uri that you can [ContentResolver.openInputStream(Uri)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ContentResolver.html#openInputStream(android.net.Uri)) on to obtain the data. This ensures item you picked is read-only, and masks it's real source - it might've been a file, provided remotely or generated by provider all together.

Comment: I've been trying to utilize it like  `context.contentResolver.openInputStream(uri)` but it throws the following exception; *Invalid URI: content://com.android.providers.downloads.documents/tree/downloads*

Comment: can you provide sample code for this because i am also getting exception.